# qt dll compatibility between compilers

Tags: c++, windows, qt, abi

Qt library states binary compatibility across major releases. But what about compatibility between different compilers?

For example, I have an application and 2 dlls that use Qt (dynamically linked). But one of them is built with MSVC and the other with MinGW. Thus they are linked to different builds of Qt library (of the same version).

**The question is**: is it possible for these dlls to work together using one shared Qt dll?
If not then what workarounds are possible considering that changing the compiler is not an option?

I looked at Qt dlls with dependency walker and I see that there are dozens of exported functions which have compiler-scpecific name mangling. So it seems that it is not possible to make them work together.

Comment: ***But what about compatibility between different compilers?*** They are incompatible because of more than 1 CRT (will cause you to have random looking heap corruption) and different implementation of the standard library (also UB).

Comment: Yes, but only one Qt dll should be used -> thus only one Qt CRT.

Comment: Qt may be from one compiler but I assume that both .dll USE Qt or even the c++ standard library. If this is the case you will have objects that cross the CRT boundaries and incompatible ABI issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not have standard ABI. That means, binaries including DLL files aren't usually compatible between compilers (they may not even be compatible between different build options on same compiler...). This is is the case with MSVC vs. MinGW, no DLL compatibility.

Plain C libraries have a defined ABI on Windows, so they may be used with any compiler (you may still run into problems with libraries having incompatible dependencies, even if ABI is compatible).

---

If recompiling one library is not an option, then the only workaround I know is to have separate processes, which then communicate using some IPC mechanism. If both libraries offer GUI elements, and you want to mix them in same GUI, that's not possible (or at least it is hard, you need to open window of other app in the window of another, sort of like an overlay).

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I was thinking that Qt was designed keeping the COM approach in mind. Seems like it's not true.
And yes, what I need is GUI interaction.

Comment: Qt is not designed like COM.

Comment: @ArtyomChirkov Qt is pure C++ (yes, some of the code is generated by *moc*, but the generated code is also pure C++, and bound by what C++ compiler does), and can't really work around such low-level incompatibilites like name mangling in binary libraries.